# Simple join in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple join query below :

```
select jobs.location_id 
from companies, 
     jobs 
where jobs.company_id = companies.id 
and companies.name = 'name';
```

it doesn't seem to get the job location of company has that name, but somehow all location_id in jobs table.

Meanwhile these two separate queries do the job:

```
select id from companies where name = 'name';
select jobs.location_id from jobs where jobs.company_id = [resulted id from query above];
```

What's wrong with the first query ?

Comment: Please show us some sample data and the output you get (e.g. copy and paste the console output - as **text** not as a screenshot please)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : hmm, when I tried to post an example on sqlfiddle, everything seems to work fine, the schema is pretty identical with the one I have locally. I will look into the problem first, will post the example later if i still have problem.

Comment: thanks for all for participation, there seems to be no problem with this query at all. I messed up locally instead. Regarding explicit joins, I'm aware of it but after being consulted by one guy on irc postgresql, if implicit join below 8 tables, it would be fine. I will optimize later on if I have problem. thanks :) Please help closing this :)

Comment: explicit joins have nothing to do with optimization or performance. They are about coding style and robustness. With implicit joins it's very easy to forget the join condition and create a cross join without intending it. This is not possible with an explicit `JOIN`. Do get used to it even for only two tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for your advice :)

Comment: Please post your solution to the problem so that others with the same issue can find this resolution. You may have to wait a while to be able to post a correct answer - however you won't get points for a correct answer to your own question! :-) Posting an accepted answer will effectively close the question.

Comment: This turned out to be a simple misunderstanding. The question is void.

Answer (score 1):

Don't join tables like that. Using a comma means cross joining tables (cartesian product).

```
select j.location_id 
from companies c 
   join jobs j on j.company_id = c.id
and c.name = 'name'
```

These two queries should produce the same execution plan and therefore the same results but this one is much clearer.

Comment: While I agree that using explicit joins is better, the example shown does **not** create a cartesian product because of the old-fashioned implicit joins in the `where` clause

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are right. The  two queries are the same. To solve the problem we need to see the data

Comment: So this answer does not really answer the question.